# How can I add results to this quiz?

Tags: html

How can I add different results to this quiz depending on people's radio button choices? Here is the quiz:

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <h1></h1>
 <form>
 <ol>
 <li> How much are you willing to spend on a phone per month?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q1"> £5-£10.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q1"> £10-£15.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q1"> £15-£20.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q1"> £20-£25.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q1"> £25-£30.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q1"> £30-£35.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q1"> £35-£40.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> Are you good with technology?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q2"> Yes.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q2"> No.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> Are you looking for an easy to use phone?</li>
 <ul> 
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q3"> Yes.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q3"> No.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> Are you looking for a modern type of phone?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q4"> Yes.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q4"> No.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> How big do you want the phone to be?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q5"> Big.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q5"> Medium.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q5"> Small.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q5"> I don't really mind.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> Do you care about the colour of the phone?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q6"> Yes.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q6"> No.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> Have you ever owned a phone before?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q7"> Yes.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q7"> No.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> Do you want to be able to use the phone to get out of awkward social situations?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q8"> Yes.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q8"> No.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> Do you want to be able to access an app store and download apps using your phone?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q9"> Yes.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q9"> No.</input></li>
 </ul>
 <li> What happened to the last phone you owned?</li>
 <ul>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q10"> I got bored of it.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q10"> It broke(I'm clumsy).</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q10"> It broke.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q10"> The contract ran out.</input></li>
 <li> <input type = "radio" name = "q10"> Other.</input></li>
 </ul>
 </ol>
 <input type = "button" value = "Submit"></input> <input type = "reset" value = "Clear"></input>
 <textarea>The right phone for you will be displayed here.</textarea> 



 </html>
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I've been trying to find an answer to this question for ages now. If you know how I can do what I've described please say. Thanks for reading.

Comment: <form action="process.php" method="get"> which opens another php file.

Comment: in the process.php you can fetch the posted data and add the results togehter.

Comment: Is it something in this html that should be hidden and just shown depending on the user choices or you mean load new content?

Comment: Just show depending on the users choices.

Answer (score 3):

Use javascript to extract the information from the html, then get the sum. You can either use jquery/ajax to do it will without submitting the page.

BTW, what do you mean add the result from the quiz?

Updated on 10/13/2013

Using javascript itself and do it in the frontend.

First, change each radio button to:

```
<li><input type = "radio" id = "q1" value="5-10" name = "q1"> £5-£10.</input></li>
```

and using JDOM to get the value

```
var name = document.getElementById('q1').value;//name will equal to "5-10"
```

after you get all options value, you can do whatever you want in logic
Hope it helps.

Comment: When I say add results I mean say somebody chooses the first radio button on every question they might get the iPhone as their result.

Comment: @KeonDavies, According to what you explained, there are two way to do it.

Comment: one is merely use javascript to do it in the front end, the other is using form submission to the backend, then using PHP/ASP/Ruby whatever backend code to get the result and send back to front end.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the if statement to do what I've described?